# Where clause when join is on many elements

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Customer** table

number = 666, ContactId= 1a1b..

**Contact** table

Id = 1a1b.., Name = Bob smith

**Address** table

Address = 350 king road, AddressType = officle, Order = 1, ContactId = 1a1b
Address = 123 queen street, AddressType = home, Order = 2, ContactId = 1a1b

SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (100)  
    dbo.Customer.Number, dbo.Contact.Name, 
    dbo.Address.StreetAddress, dbo.Address.Order 
FROM
    dbo.Customer 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Contact ON dbo.Customer.ContactId = dbo.Contact.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Address ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Address.ContactId
WHERE
    Contact.Name LIKE '%o%' OR Address.StreetAddress LIKE '%o%'
```

This return the following results :

```
666 | Bob Smith | 350 king road | 1
666 | Bob Smith | 123 queen street | 2
```

**Questions**:

I want to get the first available address (350 king road / sequence 1) and not both (even if the search string match both address)

When the match is on the second address only (like when doing a like %q% instead of like %o% in my example) I want to return this particular address and not the other one

Is it possible to do this in SQL? BTW my goal is also to get the results as fast as possible, is there any other way to do this kind of search in some "one to many" joined table?

I just need something to start with....thanks!

Comment: First available address per customer/contact? Or just first available across all customers/contacts? And how are you defining "first" - by Address.Order?

Comment: Each customer have only one contact but many addresses.   First is the first that match the search string or the first (based on Address.order) when the match is only on the contact name

Comment: Do you want Null records or not?  (why left join, the nulls are filtered out by your where clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on retrieving multiple customers but only the primary address for each you can use row_number() in a subquery and only return row 1 of each partition(customer), as such:

```
SELECT dbo.Customer.Number,
       dbo.Contact.Name,
       dbo.Address.StreetAddress,
   dbo.Address.Order
  FROM (SELECT TOP (100) Row_number()
                           OVER (
                             partition BY dbo.Customer.Number, dbo.Contact.Name
                             ORDER BY dbo.Address.Order) AS seq,
                         dbo.Customer.Number,
                         dbo.Contact.Name,
                         dbo.Address.StreetAddress,
                         dbo.Address.Order
          FROM dbo.Customer
               LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact
                      ON dbo.Customer.ContactId = dbo.Contact.Id
               LEFT JOIN dbo.Address
                      ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Address.ContactId
     WHERE Contact.Name LIKE '%o%'
        OR Address.StreetAddress LIKE '%o%') t
 WHERE t.seq = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking....thanks!!  .i'm still playing with row_number mathod and it seems to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider where Contact.Name LIKE '%o%' is likely to return more than one unique name

Values in the where negate the left so might as well use a join

```
select top 100 * 
from
(
SELECT dbo.Customer.Number, 
       dbo.Contact.Name, 
       dbo.Address.StreetAddress, 
       row_number() over (partition by dbo.Customer.Number order dbo.Address.Order) as rn
  FROM dbo.Customer 
  JOIN dbo.Contact 
        ON dbo.Contact.Id        = dbo.Customer.ContactId          
  JOIN dbo.Address 
        ON dbo.Address.ContactId = dbo.Customer.ContactId -- = dbo.Contact.Id   
 where Contact.Name LIKE '%o%' 
    or Address.StreetAddress LIKE '%o%'
) tt 
where tt.rn = 1
order by tt.Customer.Number
```

I think you can get away with just partition by dbo.Customer.Number but you may need to add dbo.Contact.Name anddbo.Address.StreetAddress

if you want to use a left then you would need
( Contact.Name LIKE '%o%' or Contact.Name is null )
and Address would need to join on dbo.Customer.ContactId
to get empty joins

Answer (score 0):

If you always want a single record based on the sort order in the Address table, simply sort the results by that field and limit the result to `TOP (1)` instead of TOP (100).

```
SELECT TOP (1)  
    dbo.Customer.Number, dbo.Contact.Name, 
    dbo.Address.StreetAddress, dbo.Address.Order 
FROM
    dbo.Customer 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Contact ON dbo.Customer.ContactId = dbo.Contact.Id 
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Address ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Address.ContactId
WHERE
    Contact.Name LIKE '%o%' OR Address.StreetAddress LIKE '%o%'
ORDER BY dbo.Address.Order ASC
```